# Outer and Inner class and static methods

Tags: java, static-methods, inner-classes

I understand that an Inner Class it's non-static and a static method from the Outer Class can't reference it.

I have this code, that doesn't work, and I understand why that doesn't work.

```
class OuterClass {
    class InnerClass{}
    public static void outherMethod() {
        InnerClass i = new InnerClass();
    }
}
```

But then I have this other code, that DOES work, but I don't understand why it's different from the first one. Why does it work?

```
class OuterClass {
    class InnerClass{}
    public static void outherMethod() {
        InnerClass i = new OuterClass.new InnerClass();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: it's not duplicated because it isn't the same question. I'm not asking about static nested classes, I'm asking about static methods and inner classes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An inner class always requires an instance of the enclosing class in order to be instantiated.

A static method of `OuterClass` doesn't have an instance of `OuterClass`, so you can't create an instance of `InnerClass` without supplying an enclosing instance (of `OuterClass`).

```
InnerClass i = new InnerClass();
```

would work only from within an instance method of `OuterClass`.

```
InnerClass i = new OuterClass().new InnerClass();
```

works from within a static method since you are creating an instance of `OuterClass` and use it as the enclosing instance for an instance of `InnerClass`.

Answer (score 3):

The key point to note here is Inner class is a member of Outer class.

So without an instance of it, you can't access it's members.

From [`docs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) directly

> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance.
>
> To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```